# WSL2 - How do I uninstall other, accidentally installed versions of python(3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I installed a bunch of python versions from a bunch of different sources while trying to upgrade from python3.8 to python3.11 on WSL2 and now I have no idea:

- which ones of the installed versions I can delete (since they were wrongly installed and are not used)
- how I can delete them
- which one is the one I am using now as python3.11 (since I would want to keep just that one)
- and which one is the system default python that should never be deleted.

In the following I'm first going to explain how I got to the point that I am at now and then explain the specific details of the problem that I'm facing trying to delete the correct versions (as in the versions that I dont need anymore) in the **TLDR** section.

I was trying to upgrade my version of python3 in WSL2 from 3.8 to 3.11. I tried a few guides to install python3.11.

First I followed [this one](https://www.debugpoint.com/install-python-3-11-ubuntu/) which installs python3.11 using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa` , `sudo apt install python3.11` and `sudo apt update`.

It then proceeds to set the default python version using `sudo apt update-alternatives` and a few other commands. This didn't work for me however, since WSL2 said that there were no update-alternatives.
When I executed `python3 --version` it still said that I have python3.8.

Therefore I then proceeded to follow [this guide](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-download-and-install-python-latest-version-on-linux/) which uses:

```
$ tar xvf Python-3.11.tgz
$ cd Python-3.11
$ ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install
$ make -j 8
$ sudo make altinstall
```

After installation however `python3 --version` still showed python3.8. Then I found [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120474/setting-python3-to-version-3-7-on-wsl) to change my system to use python3.11 using symbolic links. Now it works and `python3 --version` shows python3.11 and my system uses it.

**TLDR:** Now on to my problem of not knowing which versions to delete and how to delete them properly / thorougly / without breaking anything:

`which python3` shows `/usr/bin/python3` and `which python3.11` shows `/usr/local/bin/python3.11`. My `/usr/bin/` and my `/bin/` folder folder look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCRw0.png) now and my `/usr/local/bin/` folder looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXm5L.png).

I honestly am so confused even, as to what folder is what, as navigating like this:

```
$ cd ~
$ cd /
$ cd home/myusername/
```

leads me back to being at `~` and inside the `/` folder there is the `bin/` folder containing all this stuff but then inside `/usr/local/bin/` there is all this stuff again. Then in `/home/myusername/` there is nothing even though there should be a bin folder too according to most websites. Instead it leads me back to `~`.

So any help would be much appreciated in figuring out which of those python versions I can delete now, how I do this and what all the confusion with the directories means.

Thanks in advance!